# Trying to dynamically reallocate memory in C. The code doesn't work as planned after the first reallocation

Tags: c, memory-management

I am currently looking into memory allocation in C. The code below should read characters from standard input one by one and write them to string s. First I allocate memory for s using malloc. Initial size: CHUNK_SIZE. The counter variable counts the number of letters entered. After it becomes larger than the current size l of string s, the code should reallocate string s with the new size l + CHUNK_SIZE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    int l = CHUNK_SIZE;
    // s - is the string where to write letters from stdin
    char *s = (char *)malloc(l * sizeof(char));
    char *p = s;

    // counter for counting entered letters
    int counter = 0;
    while ((*p++ = getchar()) != '\n') {
        counter++;
        // reallocate memory if amount of entered letters more than size of s
        if (counter > l - 1) {
            l += CHUNK_SIZE;
            s = (char *)realloc(s, l * sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    *p = '\0';
    printf("%s", s);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it seems that the memory space is being successfully reallocated. But the program does not write the letter to the string after the second reallocation. With CHUNK_SIZE set to 10, only 20 letters are stored.
Entered: `This is a string and I like it`
Saved to  string: `This is a string and`

Comment: `realloc` can change the start address of the allocated block, but `p` is still pointing within the old, no longer valid block. I suggest using an index instead of pointer `p`.

Comment: You're assuming realloc() extends the size of the block at s; it may move the block. p is never adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is a long winded way to spell `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on answers provided by Ian Abbott and Paul Lynch this code is working correctly now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    int l = CHUNK_SIZE;
    char *s = (char *)malloc(l * sizeof(char));

    int counter = 0;
    while ((s[counter] = getchar()) != '\n') {
        counter++;
        if (counter > l - 1) {
            l += CHUNK_SIZE;
            s = (char *)realloc(s, l * sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    s[counter] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, p should be updated after `realloc`, for example :

```
if (counter > l - 1) {
    l += CHUNK_SIZE;
    s = (char *)realloc(s, l * sizeof(char));
    p = s + l - CHUNK_SIZE; // just after the last input char
}
```

Also you should probably check the return value of `malloc` and `realloc`.